# Let A,B,C,D be sets. A,B are not empty sets. Prove that if (AxB)U(BxA) = CxD, then A=B=C=D.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been stuck on this problem for days. Could you help me?

"Let A,B,C,D be sets. A,B are not empty sets. Prove that if (AxB)U(BxA) = CxD, then A=B=C=D."